# Akka streams flattening Flows via

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Flows can be connected with `via` like:

```
def aToB: Flow[A, B, NotUsed] = { ??? }  
def bToC: Flow[B, C, NotUsed] = { ??? }  
def aToC: Flow[A, C, NotUsed] = { aToB.via(bToC) }
```

I would like to do the equivalent of `flatMap`:

```
def aToSomeB: Flow[A, Some[B], NotUsed] = { ??? }  
def aToSomeC: Flow[A, Some[C], NotUsed] = { aToSomeB.flatVia(bToC) }
```

Is there some built-in way to do `flatVia`? It seems like a common need for things like `Option` unwrapping and error flattening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends if you are interested in keeping those `None`s around, or if you want to throw them away.

As you typed your flow as `Flow[A, Some[C], NotUsed]` is seems you are not interested in `None`s at all. This means you can easily filter them out with `collect`, e.g.

```
def aToSomeC: Flow[A, C, NotUsed] = { aToSomeB.collect{case Some(x) ⇒ x}.via(bToC) }
```

If, otherwise, you need to track the `None`s (or the `Left`s if you're dealing with `Either`s), you'll need to write your "lifting" stage yourself. This can be written fairly generically. For example, it can be written as a function that takes any flow `Flow[I, O, M]` and returns another flow `Flow[Either[E, I], Either[E, O], M`]. Because it requires fan-out and fan-in stages, usage of GraphDSL is required.

```
  def liftEither[I, O, E, M](f: Flow[I, O, M]): Graph[FlowShape[Either[E, I], Either[E, O]], M] =
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(f) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[M] => f =>

      val fIn      = builder.add(Flow[Either[E, I]])
      val p        = builder.add(Partition[Either[E, I]](2, _.fold(_ ⇒ 0, _ ⇒ 1)))
      val merge    = builder.add(Merge[Either[E, O]](2))
      val toRight  = builder.add(Flow[O].map(Right(_)))

                 p.out(0).collect{case Left(x) ⇒ Left(x)}             ~> merge
      fIn.out ~> p.in
                 p.out(1).collect{case(Right(x)) ⇒ x} ~> f ~> toRight ~> merge

      new FlowShape(fIn.in, merge.out)
    })
```

This can be used as per below

```
  def aToSomeB: Flow[A, Either[Throwable, B], NotUsed] = ???
  def aToSomeC: Flow[A, Either[Throwable, C], NotUsed] = aToSomeB.via(liftEither(bToC))
```

Note that `Option`s can easily be converted to `Either`s to leverage the same helper function.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm a bit surprised there isn't something built-in for this; isn't flattening a stream of Eithers or Optionals a common need?

Comment: I agree on the fact that it's a common need, especially if you want to keep your stream stages "referentially transparent". However, akka-stream is somewhat a lower level toolkit, and its applications are so many that it becomes tricky to clearly define what should be part of it and what shouldn't..